# Why Miracast and ordinary WiFi connection can work simultaneously?

Tags: miracast

I am really interested in the theory behind. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how does it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miracast is built over wifi. Wifi is used just as a means to transfer data. Other Applications and/or protocols just use Wifi services to transfer data, and they can run side by side. Think of playing a network game at the same time using voIP. Miracast is just one of those many applications.

For more details take a look at the OSI model. Here's a link: [WiFi on the OSI stack](http://www.engineersgarage.com/articles/what-is-wifi-technology?page=2)

Miracast is somwhere on the above layers, I am not really familiar with the standard.

Comment: very vague answer, not really saying anything

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, having simultaneous WiFi-Direct (for miracast) and normal wifi is an optional feature. It should be supported by the underlying wifi adapter and its driver.

As for theory, it looks like wifi direct and wifi are separate networks. Wifi since beginning is capable of sharing the same air for multiple networks. It depends on radio and drivers if it is possible to run both simultaneously.

In intel forum I see some issues with that and some people have to change settings or wifi router channel for miracast to work simultaneously.

Sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/1f1m2n/are_miracast_devices_able_to_use_wifi_while_using/
- http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/can-a-device-simultaneously-connect-to-a-regular-wi-fi-network-and-a-group-of
- https://communities.intel.com/thread/38534?tstart=0